# SQL Function to return sequential id's

Tags: sql-server

Consider this simple INSERT

```
INSERT INTO Assignment (CustomerId,UserId)
SELECT CustomerId,123 FROM Customers
```

That will obviously assign UserId=123 to all customers.

What I need to do is assign them to 3 userId's sequentially, so 3 users get one third of the accounts equally.

```
INSERT INTO Assignment (CustomerId,UserId)
SELECT CustomerId,fnGetNextId() FROM Customers
```

Could I create a function to return sequentially from a list of 3 ID's?, i.e. each time the function is called it returns the next one in the list?

Thanks

Comment: Add an identity column to Assignment that auto-increments automagically? - Even if they don't end up being wholly sequential they will be ordered.

Comment: Haha @AlexK. "automagically"

Comment: Can new users be added? If so, what happens? Should the assignments automatically rebalance so all customers are equally disitributed again, or are existing assignments left untouched?

Answer (score 0):

> Could I create a function to return sequentially from a list of 3 ID's?,

If you create a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers), then you can assign incremental numbers with the [NEXT VALUE FOR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/next-value-for-transact-sql) expression.

Comment: How would you use those sequential values to select from a list of other numbers, like we want in this question? `NEXT VALUE FOR` is heavily restricted in its use. Specifically, it can't be used in `ON` clauses or subqueries.

Comment: It wouldn't.  I misunderstood the question :)

Comment: I was trying to get it working with a sequence and I couldn't. Good to know it's not me. (Technically it could still work, but only if your table IDs happen to be perfectly sequential with no gaps from deletions, which is not a very likely scenario.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange requirement, but the modulus operator (`%`) should help you out without the need for functions, sequences, or altering your database structure.  This assumes that the IDs are integers.  If they're not, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` or a number of other tactics to get a distinct number value for each customer.

Obviously, you would replace the `SELECT` statement with an `INSERT` once you're satisfied with the code, but it's good practice to always select when developing before inserting.

SETUP WITH SAMPLE DATA:

```
DECLARE @Users TABLE (ID int, [Name] varchar(50))
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (ID int, [Name] varchar(50))
DECLARE @Assignment TABLE (CustomerID int, UserID int)

INSERT INTO @Customers
VALUES
(1, 'Joe'),
(2, 'Jane'),
(3, 'Jon'),
(4, 'Jake'),
(5, 'Jerry'),
(6, 'Jesus')

INSERT INTO @Users 
VALUES
(1, 'Ted'),
(2, 'Ned'),
(3, 'Fred')
```

QUERY:

```
SELECT C.Name AS [CustomerName], U.Name AS [UserName]
FROM @Customers C
JOIN @Users U
    ON 
        CASE    WHEN C.ID % 3 = 0 THEN 1
                WHEN C.ID % 3 = 1 THEN 2
                WHEN C.ID % 3 = 2 THEN 3
        END = U.ID
```

You would change the `THEN 1` to whatever your first UserID is, `THEN 2` with the second UserID, and `THEN 3` with the third UserID.  If you end up with another user and want to split the customers 4 ways, you would do replace the `CASE` statement with the following:

```
        CASE    WHEN C.ID % 4 = 0 THEN 1
                WHEN C.ID % 4 = 1 THEN 2
                WHEN C.ID % 4 = 2 THEN 3
                WHEN C.ID % 4 = 3 THEN 4
        END = U.ID
```

OUTPUT:

```
CustomerName                                       UserName
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
Joe                                                Ned
Jane                                               Fred
Jon                                                Ted
Jake                                               Ned
Jerry                                              Fred
Jesus                                              Ted

(6 row(s) affected)
```

Lastly, you will want to select the IDs for your actual insert, but I selected the names so the results are easier to understand.  Please let me know if this needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to produce `Assignment` as an automatically rebalancing view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Assignment WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
    WITH SeqUsers AS (
        SELECT UserID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY UserID) - 1 AS _ord
        FROM dbo.Users
    ), SeqCustomers AS (
        SELECT CustomerID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID) - 1 AS _ord
        FROM dbo.Customers
    )
    -- INSERT Assignment(CustomerID, UserID)
    SELECT SeqCustomers.CustomerID, SeqUsers.UserID
    FROM SeqUsers 
    JOIN SeqCustomers ON SeqUsers._ord = SeqCustomers._ord % (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SeqUsers)
;
```

This shifts assignments around if you insert a new user, which could be quite undesirable, and it's also not efficient if you had to `JOIN` on it. You can easily repurpose the query it contains for one-time inserts (the commented-out `INSERT`). The key technique there is joining on `ROW_NUMBER()`s.